# Why <svg> <text y=0> will oveflow bounding

Tags: html, css, svg

Here is my code

```
<svg viewBox={"0 0 100 100"} style={{backgroundColor: "pink"}}>
            <text y={0}>pr</text>
        </svg>
```

I'm confused, why is y=0 not in svg top-left corner but in top-left corner upside?

how to make svg element y = 0 in  top-left corner

Answer (score 1):

The `x` and `y` attributes of a `<text>` element set the start of the text **baseline**.

If you want the whole of the text to be visible, you probably want to make the `y` coordinate at least as large as the x height or the [ascender height](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascender_(typography)).

For most fonts, that normally between `0.6em` and `0.7em`.